# Batch Updates to Numerous Server 2008 Machines?

Tags: windows-server-2008, batch-processing, update

We run a lot of machines that are hosted in various datacenters (takes out the LAN based options) and we are finding the need to change Administrator account passwords for RDP (we use the same password for our admin account, just need to batch update them on a regular basis). Is there a solution that would make this possible?

Also, is there any way to handle scheduled tasks from a single machine, for other machines, via internet? We have a machine we consider the master node which is the File/Web server for the rest of the machines, so being able to use it for more of a "master" of all the systems would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell. You know. Depending on the infrastructure you run there is no reason not to ahve eeverythign in one domain. Everything CAN be srcipted these days with PowerShell. Password changes are the smallest thing you can do.

Comment: Thank you. I have never used Powershell but will definitely check it out. We don't have everything in one domain, but this actually would be quite beneficial. My question though is, can you exclude normal users from having to authenticate with the server? Each one of our client's services runs under a very limited window's user account, and we really don't need those to authenticate with the server since the service logs them in when starting the application, not the actual user.

Comment: Yes, you can. I run a domain distributed over 3 - soon 4 - locations with dc's on two. Servers still can have separate local accounts.